# How to find the current time and gmt for a shared hosting account?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I plan on using cron jobs and I need to find the current time & gmt for the server (i have access to cPanel). I can't seem to find how to do this anywhere...

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is so old, and I also trying to search the solution.
Shared Hosting, No access WHM, no access for change Date Time Server.
Check from php script is also not correct, because sometimes there are configured different Time Zone.
Change php.ini or htaccess is also not solution for Cron Job.

So for quick solution the correct simple way is using MySQL Server from phpmyadmin.

1. Go to phpmyadmin.
2. Click SQL, without selecting db or table.
3. Type

   SELECT NOW()

[image: see screenshot]

After you know the server time, you can adjust Cron Job Time with your desired time by adjusting it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

1. Select the appropriate time zone from the pull-down menu (**Server Configuration**).
2. Click **Change TimeZone**.

You can also find [more information here](http://www.hosting.com/support/cpanelvps/timezone).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Shared Linux server is that you cannot change the server time.
In such case there are two options going forward

```
1. Writing PHP script 

<?php
putenv("TZ=Asia/Calcutta");
?>


<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
?>
```

You can set the timezone in .htaccess as well. (You can create a New File and name it ".htaccess", or you can edit the existing one. The .htaccess file belongs in /public_html/ - or a subdirectory if for a subdomain or addon domain). Add the line:

```
 SetEnv TZ Asia/Calcutta
```

2. Another important way to change time zone on Shared Linux server is through changing timestamp on Email client

Each webmail client has a timezone setting, which is set to the server clock by default.

**SquirrelMail**

Go inside the webmail program and click Options at the top.
Click the first link called Personal Information.
Under Timezone Options, look for "Your current timezone:"
Change the drop down to your time zone.
Click the Submit button.
Horde

Go inside the webmail program and click Options at the top.
Click the second link called Locale and Time.
Look for "Your current time zone:"
Change the drop down to your time zone.
Click the Save Options button.

**RoundCube**

Go inside the webmail program and click Personal Settings at the top right.
Under User Interface, look for "Time zone"
Change the drop down to your time zone.
Click the Save button.

**Outlook 2007** - At any time, you can change the time zone in Outlook so that it matches your current geographic location. Please consult the Outlook Help menu for assistance with other versions.

On the Tools menu, click Options.
Click Calendar Options.
Click Time Zone.
Under Current time zone, type a name for the current time zone in the Label box.
In the Time zone list, click the time zone that you want to use.
If you want your computer clock to automatically adjust for daylight saving time (DST) changes, select the Adjust for daylight saving time check box. This option is available only in time zones that use daylight saving time (DST).
Click OK and you are done.

This has worked for me and surely will work for CRON jobs